# ARC Migration Tool on 10.7 giving error: it is not safe to remove an unused 'autorelease' message

Tags: macos, memory-management, autorelease, osx-lion

I have inherited application developed on 10.6 and I want to migrate on 10.7. I would like to comply with Automatic Reference Counting and I started it. Conversion assistant is sending me and error message: '[rewriter] it is not safe to remove an unused 'autorelease' message; its receiver may be destroyed immediately' and points to following method:

```
+ (MyClass *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur
{
    MyClass *newObject = [[MyClass new] autorelease];

    [newObject deserializeAttributesFromNode:cur];
    [newObject deserializeElementsFromNode:cur];

    return newObject;
}
```

This would be pretty much normal style (except for ugly 'new' message) in old retain/release environment, however, ARC environment does not allow this. It doesn't seem to me very good solution, but should I create poll with new directive, like this? Is this correct at all?

```
+ (MyClass *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur
{
    MyClass *newObject;
    @autorelease
    {
       newObject = [MyClass new];

       [newObject deserializeAttributesFromNode:cur];
       [newObject deserializeElementsFromNode:cur];
    }

    return newObject;
}
```

Wouldn't that release 'newObject' before return?

Answer (score 1):

The `@autorelease` block just creates a new autorelease pool around that section of code.  It doesn't do anything for the actual memory management of the code inside that block.

I think the problem the compiler is trying to point out to you is that you're returning an autoreleased object from a method that doesn't follow the naming convention for a method returning an auto-released object.

Comment: I have changed all names involved, but message remains...Thanks for suggestion anyway